# Sales and purchases = transactions?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know about any concept that group *sales and purchases* in a **single word**, I thought about **transactions**, is it correct?

I'm asking this because I'm naming a table of a database, both sales and purchases have the same columns (just 3 differ), and I want to unify them, so what should I name it?

NOTE: Maybe there's another concept, if so, please post it. "Transaction" is not necessarily the word I am trying to find.

Comment: *Transaction* is perfect

Answer (score 3):

As Jim commented, the word transaction is perfect. But you could consider using [***trade***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trade) which means the following:

> the act or an instance of buying and selling goods and services either on the domestic (wholesale and retail) markets or on the international (import, export, and entrepôt) markets

[Collins Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 2):

**Transaction** is both meaningful (with the appropriate meaning) in an everyday language sense and a very normal and well-understood term in computing.  Unless there is some sort of conflict with other terms being used, there's no reason not to use it.

Answer (score -2):

Every sale by a seller is a purchase by a buyer. The interaction is an **exchange**. Typically, money is exchanged for a good or a service. The buyer exchanges money for the good or service that is sold by the seller.  The seller exchanges the good or service for the money.

Comment: I cannot imagine why the downvotes. Care to explain? AFAIK, *exchange* is precisely the economic term for a sale and purchase. All sales and purchases = all *exchanges*.

Comment: The word *transaction* is much better. And in retail, the term *exchange* is already in use for the situation when a customer brings in an item they previously purchased but are dissatisfied with, and trades it in for a different item. If this is for a retail database, then *exchange* is the wrong word.

Comment: @PeterShor: I agree that in the world of retail merchandise *exchange* means only exchange of unwanted merchandise (also called a *return*, and essentially a reverse sale/purchase). But do we know that the question is limited to retail merchandise? In the wider world, *transaction* means all kinds of other things than a sale/purchase, and in the world of Economics, at least, *exchange* means sale/purchase - exchange of commodities, i.e., products for sale (exchange against money). Anyway, I understand the downvotes now - thanks.